# Opposite of tail: all lines except the last n lines

Tags: unix, solaris, tail, unix-utils, head

How can I discard the last n lines of a file with a unix command line filter?

That would be sort of the opposite of `tail`: `tail` discards the first n lines but pipes the rest through, but I want the command to pipe everything through *except* the last n lines.

Unfortunately I haven't found anything like that - `head` doesnt help, too. **EDIT**: At least in Solaris it does not take negative arguments.

Update: I'm mostly interested in a solution that works for big files, i.e. logfiles, where you might want to inspect what happened except in the last minutes.

Comment: FYI when using head: By placing ‘-’ in front of the number with -n option, it prints all the lines of each file but not the last N lines as shown below,

Comment: You can ask for whatever you want to ask for, but your last paragraph doesn’t make any sense to me. If “you want to inspect what happened in the last minutes”, ``tail`` is what you want.

Comment: @Scott Right: I got that backwards. Fixed it.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you have GNU `head`, you can use

```
head -n -5 file.txt
```

to print all but the last 5 lines of `file.txt`.

If `head -n` takes no negative arguments, try

```
head -n $(( $(wc -l file.txt | awk '{print $1}') - 5 )) file.txt
```

Comment: (and pray that `file.txt` is at least six lines long...)

Comment: Sadly this non-GNU version doesn't work with streams, either

Comment: @MichaelKjörling At least on ubuntu, that's not a problem. If the files has less lines than specified in `head`, an empty output is returned, with no errors.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken head -n 5 will print the first 5 lines, not all but the last 5...

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac

Answer (score 35):

```
head file.txt               # first 10 lines
tail file.txt               # last 10 lines
head -n 20 file.txt         # first 20 lines
tail -n 20 file.txt         # last 20 lines
head -20 file.txt           # first 20 lines
tail -20 file.txt           # last 20 lines
head -n -5 file.txt         # all lines except the 5 last
tail -n +5 file.txt         # all lines except the 4 first, starts at line 5
```

Comment: very good summary

Comment: A good summary of unhelpful information. Using “negative line numbers” (i.e., line numbers preceded by **```-```**) has been suggested multiple times, and the OP has said that it does not work in Solaris.

Answer (score 14):

Here's a simple way to delete the last line, which works on BSD, etc.

```
sed '$d' input.txt
```

The expression reads "on the last line, delete it". The other lines will be printed, since that is `sed`'s default behavior.

You could chain them together to remove multiple lines

```
sed '$d' input.txt | sed '$d' | sed '$d'
```

Which is a little heavy-handed, admittedly, but does only one scan through the file.

You can also take a look at this, for more answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380607/how-to-use-sed-to-remove-last-n-lines-of-a-file

Here's a one-liner adapted from one of my favorites there:

```
count=10
sed -n -e ':a' -e "1,$count"'!{P;N;D;};N;ba'
```

I had fun deciphering that one, and I hope you do, too (:
It does buffer `count` lines as it scans, but otherwise is pretty efficient.

Note: the `!` is quoted using single-quotes to avoid it being interpreted by Bash (if that's your shell). Plain double-quotes around the whole thing works for `sh`, possibly others.

Comment: For decades Unix users have been confused by man pages that said `-n` and weren’t clear whether they meant `-n` or whether they meant `-<a number>`. Your answer is similarly confusing, since it uses `N` as a variable name and also uses the `N` command.

Comment: @Scott: Fair enough; I guess my brain has been rewired to parse `sh` strings by this point, so it didn't occur to me (: I tweaked it. Part of me wanted to use the more explicit `${var}`, but then the curly braces would probably similarly confuse.

Answer (score 12):

On **MAC** the solution of getting all lines except the last N lines:

```
head -n -5 file.txt
```

**will not work**, as you will get the following error:

```
head: illegal line count -- -5
```

One of the solutions is installing coreutils and running `ghead`:

```
brew install coreutils
ghead -n -5 file.txt
```

> The GNU Core Utilities or coreutils is a package of GNU software
>   containing reimplementations for many of the basic tools, such as cat,
>   ls, and rm, which are used on Unix-like operating systems.

Comment: Welcome on the SU! I suggest to write also some textual explanation, what your code is doing and how.

Comment: @Reinstate Monica - explanation added ;)

Answer (score 4):

I'm curious why you think `head` is not an option:

```
~$ man head
...
-n, --lines=[-]K
        print the first K lines instead of the first 10; 
        with the leading `-', print all but the last K lines of each file
```

This seems to fit your purpose, using, for example:

```
head -n -20 yourfile.txt
```

Comment: Note that this only applies to GNU `head`. BSD `head` doesn't have this option, so this answer will *not* work on Solaris or other Unixes without GNU coreutils. The OP specifically tagged this with Unix and Unix-Utils too.

Comment: @slhck Not to mention the fact that the OP mentioned that this is for Solaris.

Comment: Unfortunately someone removed my mention of Solaris. But I should have mentioned anyway that the version of head does not support that.

Comment: Sorry all. Did not notice Solaris, nor was I aware of the various versions of head.

Comment: @hstoerr Solaris is now in your tags :)

Comment: does not work on mac

Comment: This is also significantly faster on my machine than the `sed $d` solution

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do it if `tail -n` won't take negative arguments is

```
tac file.txt | tail -n +6 | tac
```

This would remove the last 5 lines

Comment: Thanks! That's a nifty idea nobody came up with so far. Unfortunately that would be quite inefficient for the usecase I had in mind with this question: if that's a large file, it would not only be completely read through one or more times, as with the other solutions, but it would probably also be written to disk to temporary files by tac if it doesn't fit into memory.

Comment: @Hans-Peter Very true. Decided to write a python3 script for it. Try this https://github.com/atw31337/donkey. I recommend using the output options. They run much faster than using redirects.

Comment: Nicely written! It does, however, read through the file twice, which isn't really necessary if you buffer the last n lines, and this is a problem on large files. Personally, I don't need that anymore, but in case you have fun improving it and other people need that... There were, after all, a few likes and bookmarks on the question.

Comment: @Hans-Peter. The buffer size would be dependent on the number of lines to be removed. This could be an issue if a very large number of lines needed to be dropped from the file. In order to avoid memory related issues, I rewrote the script to use the line count method with high n values and a buffering method with lower n values; however, after testing it on a very large file, the original line count method is still faster. It seems the buffer management overhead outweighs the line count overhead...or I'm just missing something.

Comment: Nice, but for BSD-variant Mac OS X there is no tac command by default. :( This kind of defeats the use case.

Comment: Hi, me again. So in Mac OS X `tac` = `tail -r`. So, try this ugliness: `tail -r file.txt | tail -n +6 | tail -r` ...

Comment: On MacOS: bash: tac: command not found